# ASP.NET - redirect 301

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

How do I redirect permanently in ASP DOT NET? I'd like to do a 301 redirect from one page on my site to another page.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 301;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently";
    Response.RedirectLocation = "AnotherPage.aspx";
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

And in 4.0, there's a simple [`HttpResponse.RedirectPermanent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384856.aspx) method that does everything above for you:

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("AnotherPage.aspx");
```

Comment: In my helper class, I've created an extension method that allows me to type: Response.PermananentRedirect("someUrl.aspx"); - method call is: public static void PermanentRedirect(this System.Web.HttpResponse response, string uri)

Comment: Nice. Can set Response.RedirectLocation instead of calling Response.AddHeader.

Answer (score 15):

ASP.NET 4.0 Beta 1 has a **Response.RedirectPermanent()** method for doing 301 redirects, e.g.

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("AnotherPage.aspx");
```

From the [ASP.NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 Web Development Beta 1 Overview](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet40/#_Toc223325465) white paper:

> It is common practice in Web
>   applications to move pages and other
>   content around over time, which can
>   lead to an accumulation of stale links
>   in search engines. In ASP.NET,
>   developers have traditionally handled
>   requests to old URLs by using by using
>   the Response.Redirect method to
>   forward a request to the new URL.
>   However, the Redirect method issues an
>   HTTP 302 Found (temporary redirect)
>   response, which results in an extra
>   HTTP round trip when users attempt to
>   access the old URLs.
>
> ASP.NET 4.0 adds a new
>   RedirectPermanent helper method that
>   makes it easy to issue HTTP 301 Moved
>   Permanently responses.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *always* redirect from one URL to another you can use the [IIS rewrite module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

In you web.config file, add the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rule name="Redirect Source to Destination" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/source.aspx" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/destination.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
</system.webServer>
```